# WordPress database error: [Column 'date' cannot be null]

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, plugins

Im trying to connect STRIPE in my wordpress and when i click to do the payment this error come out. Do you know any way how to fix it ?
Can i make Wordpress database to accept null columns ?

WordPress database error:

```
[Column 'date' cannot be null]
INSERT INTO `wpdn_nd_booking_booking` (`id_post`, `title_post`, `date`, `date_from`, `date_to`, `guests`, `final_trip_price`, `extra_services`, `id_user`, `user_first_name`, `user_last_name`, `paypal_email`, `user_phone`, `user_address`, `user_city`, `user_country`, `user_message`, `user_arrival`, `user_coupon`, `paypal_payment_status`, `paypal_currency`, `paypal_tx`, `action_type`) VALUES ('3445', '“Maa” – Earth', NULL, '11/04/2019', '11/05/2019', '1', '1', '', '2', 'gusta', 'alli', 'abcd@yahoo.com.ar', '23232323', ' ', '', '', '', 'I do not know', '', 'Pending Payment', NULL, NULL, 'stripe')
```

Already checked stripe configuration and looks fine

Comment: you can use null in wordpress database. you can just change the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

I think your third parameter in the INSERT query having the wrong format that is why you are facing this type of error.
I will help you better if you share code instead of error.

Comment: No, actually the problem is in the final query from where you insert the data to the database table.